# Finding bugs in Lift

Tags: scala, lift

I know some scala and started to learn lift. As long as it works it is really nice. But i have big problems to find Bugs. (I'm dyslexic and most times don't see my typing errors.)

Are there some tips how to find bugs in lift?

(I think this question should already be answered somewhere but i didn't find anything on the net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IDE ([ENSIME](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime), [IntelliJ](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1347), etc) with the Scala and Lift libraries should be able to catch many errors and suggest correct spellings via auto-complete. Likewise a continuous compilation of your code (e.g. `~compile` in [sbt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/)) is a good way to catch errors and doesn't require using any specific IDE.